# C++ Declare array of unspecified length with string elements

Tags: c++, arrays, string

What I'm trying to do here is quite simple. But some way, some how I'm missing something. I'm trying to "pre-declare" an array with strictly string elements in such a way that I can update the array contents during a specific period (periodically). So here are the snippets:

```
string ShotBox[] = {}; //"Pre-Declare" array that could contain as many elements here
```

Then I have a loop within my Update container. Snippet's:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(ShotBox) - 1; i++){
            std::string soa = sPath;
            std::string so = soa + ShotBox[i];
            char *cstr = new char[so.length() + 1];
            strcpy(cstr, so.c_str());
            scPath = cstr;
}
```

All is fine with everything except the fact that whichever way I try to "pre-declare", I get a memory access violation. In this very exact snippets, the exact error is: an empty array is invalid for an array with unspecified bound.

I tried using "vector" but can't seem to work around it. What's the way to solve this? Please I don't want libraries. I need direct short methods or something of such.

Comment: std::vector<string>.

Comment: "I tried using "vector" but can't seem to work around it." -- you need to explain why you can use std::string but not std::vector.

Comment: you can't do `string ShortBox[] = {}` because it has to deduce the size of `ShortBox`, but here would cause it to be deduced as `string[0]` which is not allowed. If you want to do it this way, specify the size you want your array to be.

Comment: You can't. You can however use an stl method like a vector, linked list etc.. or you could do a dynamic array which does not require an initial size and can expand as you need it to.

Comment: @Dave S Lol... I don't even know. I guess that's the effect of switching programming languages consistently.

Comment: Try using vector with the answer below.  If you get stuck, ask a specific question and tell us the exact error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The problem of memory access violation itself is caused by your misunderstanding of `sizeof` operator. Specifically, `sizeof(ShotBox)` is the size (in bytes) of your array, not the `ShotBox[]` array size.

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(ShotBox)/sizeof(std::string); i++) {
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Inside the `for` loop `ShotBox[]` elements aren't updated at all. The only thing that happens is concatenation of `sPath` with `ShotBox[i]` into a new C string 'cstr'. If your aim is to update `ShotBox[i]` element, just add the following assignment to the end of `for` loop:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < N_SHOT_BOX; i++) {
       ...
       ShotBox[i] = so;
   }
   ```
3. It's much more convenient to use `std::vector` for working with collections of variable size:

   ```
   #include <string>
   #include <vector>
   #include <memory.h>

   int main() {
       std::vector<std::string> ShotBox{"str1", "str2", "str3"};

       for (int i = 0; i < ShotBox.size(); i++){
           std::string soa = sPath;
           std::string so = soa + ShotBox[i];
           char *cstr = new char[so.length() + 1];
           strcpy(cstr, so.c_str());
           ShotBox[i] = cstr;
       }

       return 0;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::vector<std::string>`.

The *vector* manages an internal array.

```
std::vector<std::string> ShotBox; // (empty)

ShotBox.push_back(a_string); // add a string to the internal array

std::cout << ShotBox[0] << '\n'; // print first element
```

Comment: When I comment out the Loop, I get no errors. Otherwise I have a "Vector subscript out of range error". I tried controlling that by checking `if (sizeof(ShotBox) > 0)` before it loops. Still same error.

Comment: @cmdLucas You need to find a book or a tutorial that teaches you how to use a `std::vector`.

Comment: I'll second the suggestion from @Galik .  A book I've found really useful is [Effective Modern C++](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033707.do) by Scott Meyers.

Answer (score 0):

Galik's answer suggesting std::vector is the [Modern C++](https://isocpp.org/get-started) way to do what you want to do.

The reason your code doesn't work is that the following line of code doesn't do what you think it does

> string ShotBox[] = {}; //"Pre-Declare" array that could contain as many elements here

Try adding the following to your program ...

> std::cout << sizeof(ShotBox) << std::endl;

... and you should find that you've declared an array that is zero bytes long.  Indeed some compilers will treat an empty initializer as an error if the array bounds are not specified.

In the C++ language arrays are fixed length entities.  One way to approximate a dynamic array is to use a pointer and to use memory management functions to allocate a larger array and then copy the old array contents into the new larger array.

But that is a really bad idea.

Doing it correctly with exception safety and efficiency is hard to do and if you do manage it, you'll have re-implemented std::vector which seems like wasted effort!